# NoneType object ha no attribute 'text' for object using item.find

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create an object in python that I can manipulate later on. I am using beautifulsoup for this. However I get the error

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I know where this comes from. It is coming from the fax number that sometimes has no values. Is there a way to keep the structure the code that defines company but add something to quickly check if there is a value for an item.

```
trucking_companies = soup.find_all('div',{'class' : 'well well-sm' })
for item in trucking_companies:

   company = {
   'name': item.find('span', { 'itemprop': 'name'}).text,
   'street address': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'streetAddress'}).text,
   'city': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'addressLocality'}).text,
   'state': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'addressRegion'}).text,
   'zip' : item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'postalCode'}).text,
   'phone': item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'telephone'}).text,
   'fax' : item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'faxNumber'}).text,
   }
print(company)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an `if` condition to check if you have a `None` type or not and extract `text` only if it is not `None`.

Eg: Fax from your code

Here I am assigning the text value if `fax_string` is not None else an empty string - `''`

```
fax_string = item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'faxNumber'})
'fax' : fax_string.text if fax_string is not None else '',
```

You could do the same thing for all your `company` dict keys (if you need).

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
trucking_companies = soup.find_all('div',{'class' : 'well well-sm' })
for item in trucking_companies:

   company = {
   'name': item.find('span', { 'itemprop': 'name'}).text,
   'street address': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'streetAddress'}).text,
   'city': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'addressLocality'}).text,
   'state': item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'addressRegion'}).text,
   'zip' : item.find('span', {'itemprop': 'postalCode'}).text,
   'phone': item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'telephone'}).text,
   'fax' : item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'faxNumber'}).text if (item.find('b', {'itemprop': 'faxNumber'})) !=None else "NA" ,
   }
print(company)
```

Not really sure, but I think it will work.